# TFS 2015 continues build only output changed assemblies

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

I have a solution in TFS 2015 that using continues integration build method, what i want is every check-in triggers a build that selectively only output changed dlls, exe, into the artifact folder. Is there a such configuration to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no this built-in configuration with vNext build in TFS2015.

However, a obvious solution is adding a Powershell Script on what to publish as artifacts. Using a PowerShell script to organize everything and pre-compressing in single files is the best approach for your situation.

Detail step and screenshot please take a look at this blog: [Manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: In my powershell script can i compare my artifact files by content? It doesn't seems possible with date time because the modified time are all the latest. (sorry that i'm quite new to powershell)